# REST delete from jQuery : Method Not Allowed error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, jersey

I am trying to delete a record using jQuery Ajax and caling RESTful service. However when I execute, I am getting error

```
The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource 
(Method Not Allowed).
```

What could be reason for this?

**REST service code**

```
@Path("/employee")

@DELETE
@Path("/{empNo}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void remove(@PathParam("empNo") short empNo) {
getEmployeeService().delete(empNo);
}
```

**jQuery ajax code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var empNo = 9870;
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8181/Test1/rest/employee",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(empNo),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DELETE` type and pass `empNo` with `url`. As delete method only needs empNo, so data, dataType is not needed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var empNo = 9870;
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8181/Test1/rest/employee/" + empNo, // Pass empNo
            type: "DELETE", // Use DELETE
           // data: JSON.stringify(empNo), Commented these two.
           // dataType: "json",
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a question though, what if I would want to pass a object instead of String? E.g. My method signature would like `public void remove(@PathParam("empNo") Emp emp) {`. How would I pass object?

Comment: `@PathParam` can' get Object. You should use method annotation `@Consumes("application/xml or json")` before method and method signature will plain, `void remove(Emp emp)`.

Comment: And pass from client as `data: JSON.stringify(empNo),`?

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified empno in the url

change the url to :http:// localhost:8181/Test1/rest/employee/9870

Answer (score 1):

Why is type not DELETE?

Also, why is employee number not a part of the path, since you specified it as part of the path with the @Path attribute?

Answer (score 1):

DELETE is used to delete a resource identified by a URI.

On successful deletion, return HTTP status 200 (OK) along with a response body, perhaps the representation of the deleted item (often demands too much bandwidth), or a wrapped response. Either that or return HTTP status 204 (NO CONTENT) with no response body. In other words, a 204 status with no body, or the JSEND-style response and HTTP status 200 are the recommended responses.

You also need to specify empNo as part of your URL

Modify your code as follows and try

```
 type: 'DELETE',
 url: "http://localhost:8181/Test1/rest/employee" + '/' + empNo,
```